# Why is creating elements from a text/html Document slower than creating them from an application/xml Document?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom, domparser

**Scenario**: I want to create a form and append 20k+ input fields in steps of 10 at a time.

**Implementation**: I use the JS DOMParser to create a Document and use the Document.createElement method to create these elements.

**Issue**: Using the mimetype "text/html" is often more than 5 times slower than using "application/xml".

**Questions**:

- Should I continue with the "application/xml" mimetype to create large HTML DOM hierarchies?
- Is there a reason "text/html" is so slow?
- Is there a downside to using "application/xml" when building an HTML DOM?

## Example Test

The following snippet is a basic example of what I'm trying to accomplish. It has tests for both mimetype options and outputs the elapsed time to the console.

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/malinkody/vhbe5k63/)

```js
// Controls
const htmlTest = document.getElementById('html');
const xmlTest = document.getElementById('xml');
const progress = document.getElementById('progress');
const formContainer = document.getElementById('form');
// Generate input field data for test, 2000 sets of 10 inputs each.
const inputSets = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
  const inputSet = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    inputSet.push({
      name: `abc[${i}]`,
      value: "123"
    });
  }
  inputSets.push(inputSet);
}
// Each set will be created in a task so that we can track progress
function runTask(task) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      task();
      resolve();
    });
  });
}
// The actual create form function
function createForm(isXML, callback) {
  formContainer.innerHTML = '';
  const domparser = new DOMParser();
  let doc;
  if (isXML) {
    doc = domparser.parseFromString('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><form method="POST" action="targetAction" target="_blank"></form>', "application/xml");
  } else {
    doc = domparser.parseFromString('<form method="POST" action="targetAction" target="_blank"></form>', "text/html");
  }

  const form = doc.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];

  const start = Date.now();
  console.log('===================');
  console.log(`Started @: ${(new Date(start)).toISOString()}`);
  let i = 0;
  const processTasks = () => {
    runTask(() => {
      for (let input of inputSets[i]) {
        const inputNode = doc.createElement('input');
        inputNode.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        inputNode.setAttribute('name', input.name);
        inputNode.setAttribute('value', input.value);
        form.appendChild(inputNode);
      }
    }).then(() => {
      i++;
      if (i < inputSets.length) {
        progress.innerHTML = `Progress: ${Math.floor((i / inputSets.length) * 100)} %`;
        processTasks();
      } else {
        progress.innerHTML = 'Progress: 100 %'
        const serializer = new XMLSerializer();
        // EDIT: By using the xml serializer you can append valid HTML
        formContainer.innerHTML = serializer.serializeToString(form);
        const end = Date.now();
        console.log(`Ended @: ${(new Date(end)).toISOString()}`);
        console.log(`Time Elapsed: ${(end - start) / 1000} seconds`);
        console.log('===================');
        callback && callback();
      }
    });
  };
  // Append all the inputs
  processTasks();
}

htmlTest.onclick = () => {
  createForm(false, () => {
    const tForm = formContainer.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
    tForm.submit();
  });

};

xmlTest.onclick = () => {
  createForm(true, () => {
    const tForm = formContainer.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
    tForm.submit();
  });
};
```

```html
<button id="html">text/html test</button>
<button id="xml">application/xml test</button>
<div id="progress">Progress: 0 %</div>
<div id="form"></div>
```

**EDIT**: I edited the example with the new information provided in the answer. I was able to keep the application/xml and create a valid HTML form by using the XMLSerializer to set the xml to innerHTML as a string. This way I can generate the form faster but still be able to submit it as if it were created by window.document.createElement (text/html Document).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I continue with the "application/xml" mimetype to create large HTML DOM hierarchies?

I don't really understand what you are trying to do (the big picture) so it's quite hard to say.

> Is there a reason "text/html" is so slow?"

Yes. First just creating an HTML document is way more complicated than creating an XML one.
Simply check both DOMs you created, the HTML one has way more elements.

```js
const markup = '<form></form>'
console.log(
  'text/html',
  new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(
    new DOMParser().parseFromString(markup, 'text/html')
 )
);
console.log(
  'application/xml',
  new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(
    new DOMParser().parseFromString(markup, 'application/xml')
 )
);
```

Now, your case doesn't even only create documents, it does then after create elements **and set attributes** to these.

The attributes you will set in HTML are IDL attributes that are triggering a lot of side-effects, while in the XML version they correspond to nothing and thus faster to set.

```js
const xmldoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<div/>', 'application/xml');
const xmlinput = xmldoc.createElement('input');
xmlinput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
console.log("xml input", xmlinput.type) // undefined

const htmldoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<div/>', 'text/html');
const htmlinput = htmldoc.createElement('input');
htmlinput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
console.log("html input", htmlinput.type) // "text"
```

> Is there a downside to using "application/xml" when building an HTML DOM?

**Yes**: you are not building an HTML DOM. None of the elements you are creating are inheriting from HTMLElement, and none will behave the same as their HTML correspondence.

```js
const xmldoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<div/>', 'application/xml');
const xmlinput = xmldoc.createElement('input');
xmlinput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
console.log("is HTMLElement", xmlinput instanceof HTMLElement) // false
```

So if you need an HTML DOM, you can not parse it as an XML one.

I hope you'll be able to answer yourself the first question from there.

Comment: This helped me understand why the 2 approaches had such different times even though the output form looked the same. One thing I did realize is that I cannot submit the form created with the "application/xml" Document. I'm experimenting to see if I can mix these 2 in order to improve performance while still keeping the functionality.

Comment: I edited the example with the new information provided in the answer. I was able to keep the application/xml and create a valid HTML form by using the XMLSerializer to set the xml to innerHTML as a string. This way I can generate the form faster but still be able to submit it as if it were created by window.document.createElement (text/html Document). Is this a valid approach? Or am I still creating invalid HTML?

Comment: @malinkody - You're still creating invalid HTML. To test like for like, you must do two things. 1. Put the xml form element in an `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` element; and 2. either (a) use `application/xhtml+xml` instead of `application/xml` as your mime type, or (b) use `createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "input")` instead of `createElement("input")`